# What book is the Iyun Yaakov referring to with the abbreviation כ"ח?

Tags: jewish-books, authorship

The Iyun Yaakov on Berachos daf 3a on the words "the night has 4 watches" quotes from a book that he refers to with the abbreviation כ"ח. What book is he referring to?

(In the new edition of the Ein Yaakov you can find the beginning of the Iyun Yaakov on page ט. The quote is on the next page, page י.)

Comment: I didn't look it up,but can it be a ksiv chaser?

Comment: @sam What would that mean "a ksiv chaser"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56230&st=&pgnum=124&hilite= says it's supposed to be כ"ה, which stands for כבוד הבית.

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: @Gavriel: searched on Hebrewbooks using a couple of the keywords that Iyun Yaakov quotes.